# i'm making a small project with selenium but it's too slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance, selenium

I'm making a small project with selenium. but before I can do anything, I need to wait for the whole page to load. is there anyway, for me to send keys as soon as the search bar loads?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

On top of your code so each time you try to find an element it will try for 10 seconds and if it doesn’t find it, it will raise an exception